# Let a be the smallest positive value of X

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Let a be the smallest positive value of x at which the function
f(x) =cos(x²) sin(x²) has a critical point. What is the value of f(a)?

This is what i did

I found the derivative and equated to zero

That is:
1-tanx² = 0

Therefore x² = π/4

x = √π/2

It implies  a = √π/2

F(a) = cos(√π/2)²sin(√π/2)²

F(a)= 1/2

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick guide for formatting math on this site. Please consider editing your post to make the math more readable.

Comment: What you did is correct.

Comment: Ok thanks. I wasn't sure

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:mathematical-german]??